# Button onclick change his text with an <actionStatus>

Tags: visualforce, button

I'm able to display a loading image after a click on a button.

```
<apex:commandButton id="myButton" value="Save" action="{!save}" status="saveStatus"/>

<apex:actionStatus id="saveStatus">
    <apex:facet name="start">
        <apex:image value="/img/loading24.gif" height="16" width="16" />
    </apex:facet> 
</apex:actionStatus>
```

Now, I'm wondering if there is a way to replace the button text by the loading image after a click and put the text when process is done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by using a `string` in the controller that feeds the status like so:

**NOTE:** Edited to remove bug

**Controller**

```
public String buttonStatus {public get; public set;}
....
//in constructor, set the value of the text:
buttonStatus = 'Save';

//now in save method, change the status. You need to do this, as you changed it via
//javascript when you called the save method
public PageReference save(){
...
buttonStatus = 'Save';
return null;
```

**Page**

```
<apex:commandButton id="myButton" value="Save" action="{!saveScreening}"  onclick="this.value = 'Saving...'"/>
```

Of course, you'll need to make sure you refresh the form `oncomplete`

If you want to add an image to the button, you can add this javascript function:

```
function setImage(button){
      button.value = '      Saving...';
      button.style.background = 'url(/img/loading24.gif)';
      button.style.background-position = 'no-repeat';
      button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      button.style.border = 'none';
    }
```

And call it in your onclick method.

Comment: Maybe my question is not well-formed but I don't want to have another text replacing the original text but display the loading image in the button during the process

Comment: In that case, you'll need to add and <i> element and add the image to that - in the onclick method

Comment: Actually, do this: innerHTML = '<img src="/img/loading24.gif">' in the onclick method.

Comment: But now, you'll need to define a function to do this, as you can't have < tags inside the handler

Comment: Looks like innerHTML only works for an actual button, not an input with type button. Try this stackoverflow answer for how to set the image - it's not hard. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920076/html-css-how-to-add-image-icon-to-input-type-button

Comment: Ok, finally have it working! Take a look.

Comment: I only have to change `button.style.background-position` to `button.style.backgroundRepeat` to avoid Javascript error and it works. Thanks a lot !

Comment: No worries. Glad it all worked!